# Haxe and Windows API

Tags: windows, haxe

Im trying to use the Windows API in Haxe to create a Windows application. I have already done this using ndlls and Haxe/Neko.
I tried doing it with the cpp target where I embed C++ code into the Haxe file using the new macro features in Haxe 2.09. But, as soon as I include `windows.h` it gives an error

```
./src/Main.cpp(79) : error C2039: 'RegisterClassA' : is not a member of 'hx'
./src/Main.cpp(81) : error C2660: 'RegisterClassA' : function does not take 9 arguments
Called from ? line 1
Called from BuildTool.hx line 1246
Called from BuildTool.hx line 554
Called from BuildTool.hx line 591
Called from BuildTool.hx line 710
Called from BuildTool.hx line 785
Uncaught exception - Error in building thread
Error : Build failed
Build halted with errors (haxe.exe).
```

Here is my code -

```
import cpp.Lib;

@:headerCode("#include <windows.h>")// if i comment this line or replace windows.h with another standard header file like iostream, the error goes

class Main 
{
     static function main() 
     {
           //no code here   
     }
}
```

In fact, if I replace `windows.h` with any header file from the Windows or DirectX SDK, I get the same error
Im using Haxe 2.09 and FlashDevelop. I use Windows 7. I am also using the latest version of hxcpp (version 2.09).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `<windows.h>` is #defining `RegisterClass` to `RegisterClassA` (part of the auto-magic Unicode support).

Because this is done with a text-prepropcessor macro, any code that has a symbol named `RegisterClass` (as seems to be the case with BuildTool) has it automatically swapped out for `RegisterClassA`, which obviously causes problems if somebody goes looking for the function under its proper name.

Try this:

```
@:headerCode("#include <windows.h>")
@:headerCode("#undef RegisterClass")
```

You may need to do something similar for other clashes. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080635/21475).

Comment: I understand what you mean. It makes sense. But, I needed to change the code you gave me a little bit. I had to put the undef statement before the windows.h include. Otherwise it gives the same error. Could you explain why. Anyway thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciated it.

Comment: @bharu: Before? No, I really can't explain that... Sorry! ;-)

Comment: @bharu: The only explanation I can think of is that perhaps the header code gets injected in reverse order... but that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No actually it turns out it doesn't matter which order you put it in. You were right anyway. It was actually another small error which was due to me being careless. Sorry ! Thanks again !