# #define Conflicting with Conditionally #include-d Library

Tags: c++

Here's a simplified example.  Suppose I'm writing program A using libraries B and C.  Niether library's source code can be changed and they are the only available libraries for the purpose.  Library B has a reasonable `#define` whereas Library C has a *stupid* `#define` that aliases it.  Something like, say:

```
//library_b_header.hpp
#pragma once
#define uint16 unsigned short

//...

//library_c_header.hpp
#pragma once
#define uint16 unsigned char
```

Most of the precedent I have is questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080635/others-library-define-naming-conflict).  One answer helpfully suggests, covering the range of suggestions I've seen (paraphrasing):

- Add `#undef` in your own code
- Don't directly include `library_c_header.hpp`.  If another library includes it for you, don't include *that* directly.  Instead, include it in a separate `.cpp` file, which can then expose wrapper functions in its header.
- Rename your own symbol.

The second option is close to my normal solution, but library C is huge; I can't possibly wrap all the functionality.  Even if I could, there's a good chance of screwing up, and it's certainly not portable to new releases of library C (which are also frequent).

The third option doesn't work, since this is used everywhere.  It's not just *me* that this is conflicting with; it's conflicting with *literally everything else*.  I suppose it *could* be done . . . it's just a *MORALLY WRONG `#define`, AND IT SHOULD DIE!*

The first option here is closest to what I'm trying.  The second issue is that `#include`ing library C *depends on a token defined in library B*.

The furthest I've gotten is:

```
#include <library_b/library_b_header.hpp>
#define library_b_uint16 uint16
#undef uint16

#ifdef LIBRARY_B_SYMBOL
    #include <library_c/library_c_header.hpp>
    #undef uint16
    #define uint16 library_b_uint16
#endif
```

This clearly doesn't work, but perhaps it expresses my intent.  Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: I'm a little confused - library C depends on library B but also conflicts with library B?

Comment: @MichaelBurr The libraries are unrelated, but the program being written can only include C iff a symbol is defined in B.  See example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compiler supports the `push_macro` and `pop_macro` pragmas, you may be able to use them like so:

```
#include <library_b/library_b_header.hpp>

#pragma push_macro("uint16")
#undef uint16
#include <library_c/library_c_header.hpp>
#pragma pop_macro("uint16")
```

(These pragmas are nonstandard, but they are widely supported.  Visual C++, gcc, clang, and the Intel C++ Compiler all support them.)

Yes, you need to do this everywhere you include a header from Library C that defines this macro, but this is usually simplified by writing your own header that wraps inclusion of the Library C headers, then including that header wherever Library C is needed in your project.

Comment: Working on both MSVC and g++ is enough for my purposes.  +1 for teaching me `push_macro`/`pop_macro`.  Accept for solving the problem.  Thanks!